# jQuery - Different selectors for descendants?

Tags: jquery, descendant

Can someone please explain how the selectors work for the different descendants?
I've looked a bit online but the descriptions I've found so far don't seem to be terribly different.

For example, what's the difference between these three?

```
$('table tr')
$('table > tr')
$('table + tr')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Matches all elements with tag name tr that are descendents of table.
2. Matches all elements with tag name tr that are direct children of table.
3. Matches all elements tr immediately preceded by sibling table.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes a lot more sense now as to why it's working the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

table tr is a bad example for this because you cant have a tr without table, and the also don't need the jquery function

```
p span
```

this one selects all the span tags inside the p tag

```
p > span
```

this one selects only the first nested span tag inside the p

```
p + span
```

selects only that span tag, that comes right after the p in your markup

Answer (score 0):

You can't have looked terribly hard, [jQuery's documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) is pretty clear on the subject.

Given some simple markup,

```
<div>
  <span id="A"></span>
  <p><br /><span id="B"></span></p>

  <form>
    <span id="C"></span>
    <span id="D"></span>
  </form>
</div>
```

This is how selects will work:

- `$("div span")` matches any span within a div, however far nested with a div they might be (A,B,C,D)
- `$("div > span")` matches spans which are immediate descendts of divs (A)
- `$("br + span")` matches span next to a br (B)
- `$("form span")` matches spans within a form (C, D)
- `$("form span:first")` matches only the first span with a form (C)

Comment: Yeah, I gotta say - this is a pretty lazy question.